# CSS Emoticons plugin and realtime update of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code read the pms, that is stored inside a php file and print them on the screen every 0.01 second to be in realtime or work dynamic, but i'm using a "CSS Emoticons plugin", it works and show the emoticons, but i can't use the animate one or i can, but it would not finish, it would restart every 0.01 second unless i turn it off. I want to use it with the dynamic text, but i dont know how. Please help me out guys

```
function updateStats(stat) {
    var stat = ["MSG", "NAME"];
    var url = "POST.php";
    $.each(stat, function (i, key) {
        $.post(url, {
            stats: key
        }, function (data) {
            $("#" + key).html(data);
            $('div.icon').emoticonize({
                //delay: 800, 
                //animate: false
            });
        });
    });
}
setInterval(function () {
    updateStats("updateStats");
}, 10);
```

Comment: R u sure u will get response from ajax in 0.01 seconds?

Comment: I'm getting the response in 0.01 second, but even if i change it to 1 second.. that wont do ..what i need

Comment: just try setting interval to 10 seconds and see whether it is working......

Comment: I know it will full animate on 10 seconds, but then it will read every 10 seconds not, realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this...

```
var to;
function updateStats(stat) {
    var stat = ["MSG", "NAME"];
    var url = "POST.php";
    clearTimeout(to);
    $.each(stat, function (i, key) {
       $.post(url, {
           stats: key
       }, function (data) {
           $("#" + key).html(data);
           $('div.icon').emoticonize({
              //delay: 800, 
              //animate: false
           });
           to = setInterval(function () {
              updateStats("updateStats");
           }, 10);    
       });
    });
}
to = setInterval(function () {
    updateStats("updateStats");
}, 10);
```